# While setting Minimum date for one year calendar is showing hidden date in the calendar header

Tags: android, kotlin, android-calendar, android-components

I set a minimum date to the `DatePicker` (`#setMinDate`) and though dates before the minDate are not displayed, there's a bug that if i change the year to past year (with same date as current day), and press OK, the date chosen is a date before the minDate i gave.

This was the code i used

```
private fun customCalender() {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        val cal1 = Calendar.getInstance()
        val dialog = DatePickerDialog(this@MainActivity, { arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3 ->
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "" + arg1 + "/" + (arg2 + 1) + "/" + arg3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
        cal1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1)
        dialog.datePicker.minDate = cal1.timeInMillis
        dialog.datePicker.maxDate = System.currentTimeMillis()
        dialog.show()
    }
```

Please refer the screen shots for references ,
[While i am selecting a date a day before the maximum date i.e i am selecting 2020 Mon,sept 28 as it showing in header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UHbu.png)

[After switching to previous date without changeing any thing , In the header its showing 2019 sat,sept 28 which was in hidden date in calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTYAX.png)

I have searched for solution but not yet resolved ,
please help me ,
Thank you

Comment: On Which android version you are testing . I also faced Some issues with `DatePickerDialog` min max dated on API-21 devices . So this can be specific to OS version too .

Comment: @ADM mine OS version is API-29, i think this is issue was there in all API version

Comment: Not sure . you can try `MaterialDatePicker` its an enhanced widget with Material UI .you can find some sample easily on it

Comment: @ADM But MaterialDatePicker have another major problem that OK button was not shown for most of the devices , There was a issue already raised forthis
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1346